# A class clickable inside UL

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following:

```
<ul>
   <li>....</li>
   <a class="close">Close</a>
</ul>
```

But when I use the following JQuery:

```
$(function()
{
    $('.close').click(function()
    {
        console.log("Close");
    });
});
```

Won't register the click event, however, if I move the `a tag` outside of the `ul` then it works.

How do you specify a class within a `ul` without making all of the other elements clickable also?

Comment: the `a` tag should be in a `li` element

Comment: did u tried to create '<li class="close"></li>'? or add "a" tag into another "li".
unordered list must contain "li" as a child. otherwise it won't work

Comment: This is not legitimate way to define element inside ul . direct child of ul/ol should be "li" .

Comment: @Ika Pkhakadze - I can't do that because for each staff member, they are contained in a `li` so creating a `li` for `close` creates a new staff member - If that makes sense?

Comment: Do you have an option to separate that a tag from ul?

Comment: @IkaPkhakadze Nope. Not at all. Sadly. I did not write this code, I'm just working with this code and trying to make improvements but it's difficult because of the way it's structured

Comment: U have to do something. U cant handle click event with incorrect structured list.
i updated my answer. hope it will help

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/efu27tk8/), there is nothing wrong in your code! Don't know why not working in your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of this:

```
<ul id="StaffList">
  <li>....</li>
</ul>

<a for="StaffList" class="close">Close</a>
```

script:

```
$(function()
{
    $('.close').click(function()
    {
        var list = $("#"+$(this).attr('for'));
        //here u have a rerfference of list above.
        //u can do whatever u want with it
        //for example list.hide();
        console.log("Close");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, I will also tidy up the UL classes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ul>
   <li class="close"><a href="#">Close</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But do not have the option to do this. The developer who made this has done it so that for each staff member, they are in an `li` so creating a new `li` for `close` only creates another staff member - If this makes sense?